# Delphi regular expression, ignoring LineFeed in matched text

Tags: regex, delphi

I want to search for the following regular expression

```
^[ ]*,$
```

in the following text :

```
  ,[LF]
  ,[LF]
```

- My problem is that Delphi finds the expression, but the matched text doesn't include the LF.
  Effectively I want to removes the lines from my source code.
- I'am using TPerlRegEx with delphiXe8
- In the example [LF] is the linefeed ($0D $0A)
- I Tested several flags combinaisons in TPerlRegExOptions
- This works perfectly in SublimeText 3

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you sure it works in SublimeText3? I think you should use `^\s*,\[.*\]\s*$` instead.

Comment: @Henry, if you are using a PCRE regex, you need `(?m)^[ ]*,\R` (add a `?` after `\R` to also match the last line in the text). And the backslash must be doubled (`\\R`) since the string literals are C strings in Delphi.

Comment: You shouldn't use TPerlRegEx from System.RegularExpressionsCore directly, instead take a look at TRegex from System.RegularExpressions

Comment: Many thanks for all your answers. I've  `^[ ]*,\R` and it works find for me. For sublime text I made a little mistake I was using in fact `^[ ]*,\n`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a PCRE regex, you can match zero or more spaces at the stsart of a line followed with a comma followed with a newline sequence with

```
(?m)^[ ]*,\R
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN4wL6/1). Note that `(?m)` is a multiline modifier making `^` match a location at the beginning of a line (after `\n`). `\R` matches any newline sequence.

Add a `?` after `\R` to also match the last line in the text that has no newline sequence at the end.

Comment: there is no need for the doubling, `\R` is perfectly fine

Comment: Just tested it: `Assert(TRegex.Replace('  ,' + sLineBreak + '  ,' + sLineBreak, '(?m)^[ ]*,\\R)', '').IsEmpty);` runs and works perfectly, with doubled backslash it raises an ERegularExpression error.

Comment: @SebastianProske: I have checked it, too, and it appears that note of mine was not relevant. I removed it. Thank you for testing.